# SetValue in reflection returning object does not match target type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am looping through a class with multiple properties and am searching for any textboxes that have the same ID. If there is a match then I want to update the property value to that of the textbox value, but I am getting this error:

> Object does not match target type

This is the code:

```
foreach (var prop in contactInfo.GetType().GetProperties())                    
{                        
    var ctrl = WizardCampaign.FindControl(prop.Name) ?? Page.Master.FindControl(prop.Name);        

    if (ctrl != null)
    {
        if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            var r = (TextBox)ctrl;                                                                                                                                                                                             
            prop.SetValue(prop, r.Text, null);                                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `if(ctrl != null)` and `if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))` you can combine them and include objects derived from textbox using `if(ctrl is TextBox)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look here:

```
prop.SetValue(prop, r.Text, null);
```

`SetValue` is supposed to take the object you want to change as the first parameter, but you are passing the `PropertyInfo` object. I believe your actual code should be:

```
prop.SetValue(contactInfo, r.Text, null);
```